# Number of walks of given length issued from one point in a (N,E,W) grid system

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I understand how this idea works. Use the Binomial theorem and plug in the two numbers on the point for North and East into the binomial equation, but my specific problem deals with the possibility of going west too. Here's the specific problem he gave us

[image: My problem]

Comment: This problem does not specify an ending point that all paths must reach, so it is unlike the problem that gives the binomial coefficient. In fact, if you had only north and east travel, and could walk $n$ blocks with no predetermined destination, you would have $2^n$ possible paths.

Comment: Whoever wrote this problem did not appear to think it through very well. They say the reason to forbid EW or WE is because of two paths (of very different lengths) that end at the same point--but it makes no objection to considering NNN, NENWN, and NWNEN, all of which end at the same point, as separate paths. I would recommend ignoring everything in the problem statement except the sentence that starts with the words "More mathematically". The rest of it just obscures things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enumerating the results for small $n$ :

---

$n=1$

$E,N,W$

Total $3$

---

$n=2$

$EE,EN,NE,NN,NW,WN,WW$

Total $7$

---

$n=3$

$EEE,EEN,ENE,ENN,ENW,NEE,NEN,NEW,NNE,NNN,NNW,NWN,NWW,WNE,WNN,WNW,WWN,WWW$

Total $17$

---

$n=4$

$EEEE,EEEN,EENE,EENN,EENW,ENEE,ENEN,ENNE,ENNN,ENNW,ENWN,ENWW,NEEE,NEEN,NENE,NENN,NENW,NNEE,NNEN,NNNE,NNNN,NNNW,NNWN,NNWW,NWNE,NWNN,NWNW,NWWN,NWWW,WNEE,WNEN,WNNE,WNNN,WNNW,WNWN,WNWW,WWNE,WWNN,WWNW,WWWN,WWWW$

Total $41$

---

We can see that the number of length-$n$ walks starting with $N$ equals the total number of length-$(n-1)$ walks... And the number of length-$n$ walks starting with $E$ equals the number of length-$(n-1)$ walks starting with $N$ or $E$... And the total number of length-$n$ walks is the sum of those starting with $N$ and $E$ and $W$.

Define the number of walks starting with $N$ as $a_n$, and with $E$ (or $W$) as $b_n$. Then the total is $a_n+2b_n$, and

$$a_n = a_{n-1}+2b_{n-1}$$

$$b_n = a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}$$

and of course $a_1=b_1=1$. This completely determines the sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$.

This is a first-order linear system, which can be written with matrices as

$$\begin{bmatrix} a_n\\b_n \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\1&1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_{n-1}\\b_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$$

and has the solution

$$=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\1&1 \end{bmatrix}^n\begin{bmatrix}a_0\\b_0\end{bmatrix}$$

where $a_0=1,b_0=0$.

---

Sequence of powers of the matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\1&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}3&4\\2&3\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}7&10\\5&7\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}17&24\\12&17\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}41&58\\29&41\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}99&140\\70&99\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}239&338\\169&239\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}577&816\\408&577\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1393&1970\\985&1393\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}3363&4756\\2378&3363\end{bmatrix},\cdots$$

It can be diagonalized for a more explicit formula (thanks @ploosu2) :

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\1&1\end{bmatrix}^n = \frac14\begin{bmatrix}-\sqrt2&\sqrt2\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}(1-\sqrt2)^n&0\\0&(1+\sqrt2)^n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-\sqrt2&2\\\sqrt2&2\end{bmatrix}$$

$$= \begin{bmatrix}\frac12\Big((1+\sqrt2)^n+(1-\sqrt2)^n\Big)& \frac{\sqrt2}2\Big((1+\sqrt2)^n-(1-\sqrt2)^n\Big)\\ \frac{\sqrt2}4\Big((1+\sqrt2)^n-(1-\sqrt2)^n\Big)&\frac12\Big((1+\sqrt2)^n+(1-\sqrt2)^n\Big)\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, the desired number is

$$a_{n+1} = \frac12\Big((1+\sqrt2)^{n+1}+(1-\sqrt2)^{n+1}\Big)$$

$$= \sum_k\binom{n+1}{2k}2^k$$

Comment: You can diagonilize the matrix for a formula for the power https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B1,2%5D,%5B1,1%5D%5D