# Walking on an infinite grid

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

*I am sure someone has asked a similar question already, but I wasn't able to find it.*

So lets get started: We have an infinite grid with coordinates out of $ \mathbb{Z} $. Lets say the first coordinate is the X and the second is the Y. We start at some position on the grid (lets say $ (2, 2) $) and now want to go to an other position (lets say $ (42, 2) $). To do that we could go the following steps (for example):
$$A=(+1, 0)$$
$$B=(+1, +1)$$
$$C=(+1, -1)$$
Now I want to know the number of possible ways using the steps from above.

I already had some ideas - I'll list them here too for inspiration:

1. The step A has a weight of one and the step B and C has a combined weight of 2. So my mission is to find the number of their combinations to reach 40 (see example from above).
   **BUT this doesn't work because combinations like 'BAC' are also valid.**
2. I count the possible ways to perform the steps B and C: If n equals the number of steps into the right direction, so i can go B on $n-1$ steps (the last one is impossible, because for now I start with up only) and it corresponding down step can be on $n-2$ steps and so on...
   **This doesn't work, because I could go on $n-1$ steps up and on the n-th all down. Additionally things like 'BCCAB' are with this model also not possible.**
3. Well, I can see a pattern there (n equals steps to the right):

   - 40xA; 0xB+C -> 1 possible way
   - 38xA; 1xB+C -> $ n * (n-1) $ possible ways
   - 36xA; 2xB+C -> $ n * (n-1) * (n-2) * (n-3) $ possible ways
   - 34xA; 3xB+C -> $ n * (n-1) * (n-2) * (n-3) * (n-4) * (n-5) $ possible ways

...so maybe something like this: $ \prod\limits_{i=0}\limits^{n/2-1} ( (n-i*2) * (n-i*2-1) ) $

So, anyone has an idea or hint for me?

EDIT: Added third idea.

Comment: The number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(42,2)$ is the coefficient of $t^2$ in $(t^{-1}+1+t)^{42}$.

Comment: Sir isn't it $\binom{44}{2}$ . you have to walk 44 steps and you have to turn to y 2 times somewhere between. or $\binom{44}{42}$ which is same

Comment: read my comment  if it helps

Comment: Slightly different problem, but the overall reasoning might be of use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3086343/find-number-of-ways/3086424#3086424

Comment: @Rishi Hmmm, that sound really good! Lets see... If i want to allow any number of up/down steps... Something like the sum from zero to n/2 over the binom? But why 44 steps? You start at 2 and have to get to 42 -> 40 steps! The steps from above (ABC) are ONE step (so right, up+right (=diagonal), down+right (=diagonal))!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Could you give an idea of why that is?

Comment: I think it will work if you don't come backwards

Comment: Looks similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2960334/number-of-walks-from-one-point-to-a-length-on-a-grid-system

Comment: @mr_e_man : no, this question is only similar for the authorized steps  but the objective "find the number of paths of length $n$" isn't at all the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We  encode  the steps with $x$ when going a step horizontally in $x$-direction and with $y$ when going vertically in $y$-direction. This way $A,B,C$ become
\begin{align*}
&A=(1,0)\quad\to x^1y^0\\
&B=(1,1)\quad \to x^1y^1\\
&C=(1,-1)\ \to x^1y^{-1}\\
\end{align*}
To  go one step either $A$ or $B$ or $C$ is encoded as
\begin{align*}
x+xy+\frac{x}{y}
\end{align*}

Note the number of paths from $(2,2)$ to $(42,2)$ is due  to symmetry equal to the number of paths  from $(0,0)$ to $(40,0)$. We need $40$ steps to go from $(0,0)$ to $(40,0)$  and so we consider
\begin{align*}
[x^{40}y^{0}]\left(x+xy+\frac{x}{y}\right)^{40}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
where we conveniently use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^ny^m]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^ny^m$ in a series $A(x,y)$.

> We  obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^{40}y^{0}]}&\color{blue}{\left(x+xy+\frac{x}{y}\right)^{40}}\\
> &=[x^{40}y^0]x^{40}\left(1+y+\frac{1}{y}\right)^{40}\\
> &=[y^0]\sum_{k=0}^{40}\binom{40}{k}\left(y+\frac{1}{y}\right)^k\tag{2}\\
> &=[y^0]\sum_{k=0}^{40}\binom{40}{k}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}y^jy^{-(k-j)}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{40}\binom{40}{k}[y^k]\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}y^{2j}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{20}\binom{40}{2k}[y^{2k}]\sum_{j=0}^{2k}\binom{2k}{j}y^{2j}\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^{20}\binom{40}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
>   in accordance with the result of @JeanMarie.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we apply the rule $[x^p]x^q=[x^{p-q}]$ and apply the binomial theorem to $\left(1+\left(y+\frac{1}{y}\right)\right)^{40}$.
- In (3) we apply the rule $[y^p]y^q=[y^{p-q}]$ again.
- In (4) we observe that only even powers $2j$ do contribute. So we need only to consider even indices $2k$.
- In (5) we finally select the coefficient of $y^{2k}$.

> **Note:**
>   The coefficients of $x^0$ in the expansion of $\left(x+1+x^{-1}\right)^n$ are called *[central trinomial coefficients](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralTrinomialCoefficient.html)*. They do *not* admit a closed formula which is shown in *[this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291711/help-me-to-simplify-sum-limits-i-0-lfloor-fracr2-rfloor-binomri-b/2296243#2296243)*.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your problem is equivalent to find the number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(40,0)$. This is what we are going to assume.

Considering $A,B,C$ as vectors, we are in a first step looking for the number of triples $(m,n,p)$ of integers such that $$m\binom{1}{0}+n\binom{1}{1}+p\binom{ \ \ 1}{-1}=\binom{40}{0} \ \iff \ \ \begin{cases}m+n+p&=&40\\n-p&=&0\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

$$\iff \ \ \begin{cases}m+2n&=&40& \ \ \ (a)\\n&=&p& \ \ \ (b)\end{cases}.\tag{2}$$
which amounts to say :

$$\text{Determine (first) the ordered pairs of integers} \ (m,n) \ \text{such that} \ m+2n=40$$

(2) implies that $m=2(20-n)$ is an even number : $m=2k$ for $k=0,1,\cdots 20.$

Therefore, taking (2)(b) into account :

$$(m,n,p)=(2k,20-k,20-k)=(0,20,20),(2,19,19),(4,18,18), etc...$$

As a consequence, each $k$ it remains to constitute a word of $40$ letters $A,B,C$, i.e.

> place into $40$ slots : $m=2k$ letters "$A$"s, $(20-k)$ letters "$B$"s, and $(20-k)$ letters "$C$"s  as well.

Once the $2k$ "slots" for letters "$A$" have been attributed, we have to place the same amount of letters $B$ and $C$ i.e., $20-k$ letters $B$ and as many letters "$C$". We consider only placement of letters "$B$" (Placing letters  "$C$" hasn't to be considered : they occupy the remaining "slots"). This boils down to the following count :

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{20} \binom{40}{2k}\binom{40-2k}{20-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{20} \frac{40 !}{(2k)! (20-k) ! (20-k) !}$$

I don't know if one can give a close expression to this sum...